# Angular set tag as selected

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'd like to set the ng-class of a optiones-element as active. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

This is my option-menu:

```
 <select>
  <option ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</option>
 </select>
```

and the item "one" should be active

```
<select>
     <option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{selected: item=='one'}">
          {{item}}     
      </option>
 </select>
```

It doesn't work. Does anyone know how to set the option tag as active?

An example of how it works is this:

```
<select>
  <option>Blue</option>
  <option selected>Green</option>
  <option>Red</option>
</select>
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: Oh, its not ng-class .. its ng-selected ... thx

Answer (score 2):

Below is the right way "select" works in Angularjs, notice the included ng-model directive, if missing it doesn't work.

```
<select ng-model="selectedItemId" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
  <option value="">-- choose item--</option>
</select>
```

to make an item of the list active, just set SelectedItemId variable assigned to ng-model at controller side.

```
   $scope.selectedItemId = 1; //the Id belonging to the option to be selected
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you want to loop over the options using ng-repeat and then manually select the right option. It is nicer to use the select directive of Angular in that case:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="items"></select>
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select for more information.

Comment: That's very nice. The ng-model is set to the selected option as well. That's what I need, tyvm